# Jackson json streaming api for multiple occurances

Tags: jackson

I'm trying to parse some json using jackson and i've based my code on the examples on the site but i'm not getting parse error as the field is returning null. i've listed my parse code and my classes below, could anyone advise me on where i've gone wrong please ?

```
String json2 = "[{\"odd\":\"110601\",\"oda\":\"MAN\",\"odt\":\"0655\",\"oad\":0,\"oaa  \":\"IBZ\",\"oat\":\"1045\",\"rdd\":7,\"rda\":\"IBZ\",\"rdt\":\"1130\",\"rad\":7,\"raa\":\"MAN\",\"rat\":\"1315\",\"d\":7,\"sp\":[{ \"s\": \"test\", \"p\": \"1\" },{ \"s\": \"test\", \"p\": \"2\" },{ \"s\": \"test\", \"p\": \"3\" },{ \"s\": \"test\", \"p\": \"4\" }]}]";
    JsonFactory f = new JsonFactory();
    JsonParser jp = f.createJsonParser(json2);
    Flight2 flight2 = new Flight2();
    jp.nextToken(); // will return JsonToken.START_OBJECT (verify?)
    while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
        String fieldname = jp.getCurrentName();
        jp.nextToken(); // move to value, or START_OBJECT/START_ARRAY
        if ("sp".equals(fieldname)) { // contains an object
            FlightSP flightsp = new FlightSP();
            while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
                String namefield = jp.getCurrentName();
                jp.nextToken(); // move to value
                if ("s".equals(namefield)) {
                    flightsp.setS(jp.getText());
                }else if ("p".equals(namefield)) {
                    flightsp.setP(jp.getText());
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Unrecognized field '"+fieldname+"'!");
                }
            }
            flight2.setFlightSP(flightsp);
        }else if ("odd".equals(fieldname)){
            flight2.setOdd(jp.getText());
        }else if ("oda".equals(fieldname)){
            flight2.setOda(jp.getText());
        }else if ("odt".equals(fieldname)){
            flight2.setOdt(jp.getText());
        }else if ("oad".equals(fieldname)){
            flight2.setOad(jp.getText());
        }else if ("oaa".equals(fieldname)){
            flight2.setOaa(jp.getText());
        }else if ("oat".equals(fieldname)){
            flight2.setOat(jp.getText());
        }else if ("rdd".equals(fieldname)){
            flight2.setRdd(jp.getText());
        }else if ("rda".equals(fieldname)){
            flight2.setRda(jp.getText());
        }else if ("rdt".equals(fieldname)){
            flight2.setRdt(jp.getText());
        }else if ("rad".equals(fieldname)){
            flight2.setRad(jp.getText());
        }else if ("raa".equals(fieldname)){
            flight2.setRaa(jp.getText());
        }else if ("rat".equals(fieldname)){
            flight2.setRat(jp.getText());
        }else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unrecognized field '"+fieldname+"'!");
        }
    }
    jp.close(); // ensure resources get cleaned up timely and properly

public class Flight2{

@Id
Long id;
private String _odd;//out_departure_date
private String _oda;//out_departure_iata_code;
private @Unindexed String _odt;//out_departure_time;
private @Unindexed String _oad;//out_arrival_date;
private String _oaa;//out_arrival_iata_code;
private @Unindexed String _oat;//out_arrival_time;
private @Unindexed String _rdd;//rtn_departure_date;
private @Unindexed String _rda;//rtn_departure_iata_code;
private @Unindexed String _rdt;//rtn_departure_time;
private @Unindexed String _rad;//rtn_arrival_date;
private @Unindexed String _raa;//rtn_arrival_iata_code;
private @Unindexed String _rat;//rtn_arrival_time;
private String _d;//duration;
private @Unindexed FlightSP _flightsp;//table containing just supplier and price 

public void setFlightSP(FlightSP flightsp){_flightsp = flightsp;}
public void setOdd(String odd) {_odd = odd;}
public void setOda(String oda) {_oda = oda;}
public void setOdt(String odt) {_odt = odt;}
public void setOad(String oad) {_oad = oad;}
public void setOaa(String oaa) {_oaa = oaa;}
public void setOat(String oat) {_oat = oat;}
public void setRdd(String rdd) {_rdd = rdd;}
public void setRda(String rda) {_rda = rda;}
public void setRdt(String rdt) {_rdt = rdt;}
public void setRad(String rad) {_rad = rad;}
public void setRaa(String raa) {_raa = raa;}
public void setRat(String rat) {_rat = rat;}

public FlightSP getFlightSP(){return _flightsp;}
public String getOdd() {return _odd;}
public String getOda() {return _oda;}
public String getOdt() {return _odt;}
public String getOad() {return _oad;}
public String getOaa() {return _oaa;}
public String getOat() {return _oat;}
public String getRdd() {return _rdd;}
public String getRda() {return _rda;}
public String getRdt() {return _rdt;}
public String getRad() {return _rad;}
public String getRaa() {return _raa;}
public String getRat() {return _rat;}
}

public class FlightSP {
@Id
Long id;
private @Unindexed String _s, _p;

public void setS(String s) {_s = s;}
public void setP(String p) {_p = p;}

public String getS() {return _s;}
public String getP() {return _p;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the exact answer, but I am wondering as to why you are not using data-binding but manual code to do the same? Data-binding would shrink code to just couple of lines, if applicable.

But what exactly is the error? And for what kind of JSON?

Comment: the json is included in the string on line 1. i'm using streaming as its the fastest possible way to do the task. performance of the application is critical

Comment: Ok. Just asking (wrt perf) since it seems to be doing DB tasks, so json processing may not be the bottleneck. But streaming can have bit more (30-50%) throughput, so fair enough.
But I was still wondering about the error you are getting: what is the message?

Comment: String fieldname = jp.getCurrentName();
fieldname' contains null and generates an exception on first token

Comment: Ah. Looking at JSON, code, aren't you forgetting to handle START_ARRAY that comes before START_OBJECT?

Comment: hadn't seen the START_ARRAY command ! that was the problem - thanks for your help :-)